# TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useEffect)(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have changed the code below to `!_product && fetchProduct(productId)`, which has caused the error because this returns the `fetchProduct` function and being executed as the cleanup function. I rewrote it to the code below and the error still persists. The app was created using `create-react-app`

```
import { faMinus, faPlus, faTrash } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addQuantity, deleteProductFromCart, fetchProduct, substractQuantity } from '../../store/actions';
import { checkPriceForDiscount } from '../../utils';
import Loading from './Loading';

const visible = (cart, productId) => {
    let { quantity } = cart.products.find(p => p.id === productId)
    return quantity ? "" : "fade-out"
}

const ProductPreview = ({ product, price }) => {
    if (price.discounted) {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="box">
                    <div className="ribbon text-center">
                        -{price.discountInPercentage}% for <br />{price.matches} item Discount
                    </div>
                    <img className="preview" src={product.image} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="box">
                <img className="preview" src={product.image} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const Product = ({ productId, cart, carts, products, fetchProduct, addQuantity, substractQuantity, deleteProductFromCart }) => {

    const [price, setPrice] = useState(null)
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        let _product = products.find(p => p.id === productId)
        if (!_product) fetchProduct(productId)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        let _product = products.find(p => p.id === productId)
        if (_product) setProduct(_product)
    }, [products])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (product) {
            let _price = checkPriceForDiscount(carts, product)
            if (_price) setPrice(_price)
        }
    }, [product, cart])

    (!price || !product) && <Loading />
    

    return (
        <div className={`product ${visible(cart, productId)}`}>
            <div className="title-wrapper">
                <div className="title">
                    {product.title}  ({product.category})
                </div>
            </div>
            <ProductPreview {...{ product, price }} />
            <div className="text">
                <div className="description">
                    {product.description}
                </div>
                <div className="price">
                    $ {price.rawPrice}
                </div>
                <div className="shop-actions">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon id='substractQuantityIcon' className='pointer' icon={faMinus} onClick={() => substractQuantity(cart.id, productId)} />
                    {cart.products.find(p => p.productId === productId).quantity}
                    <FontAwesomeIcon id='addQuantityIcon' className='pointer' icon={faPlus} onClick={() => addQuantity(cart.id, productId)} />
                    <button className='pointer grow_on_hover' onClick={() => deleteProductFromCart(cart.id, productId)}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} /> Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        carts: state.carts,
        products: state.products,
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { addQuantity, substractQuantity, deleteProductFromCart, fetchProduct }
)(Product);
```

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this error. Can you share the whole component code?

Comment: Does it remove the error when you remove the ` (!price || !product) && <Loading />` line?

Comment: @CasperKuethe it throws another saying that `product.title` undefined